# Loading unknown amount of files from multiple subfolders

Tags: python, pandas, loading

I am getting detector data in varying amounts inside multiple subfolders, and I need to combine them into a pandas dataframe basically.

I was wondering if there is any smart way to make this?

using

find . -name *.cvs | wc -l

gives: 1464 files , for instance

I will then have to load it into a dataframe.

The directory structure might be something similar:

```
             sub-sub-sub-data
            /
main folder-sub-sub-sub-data
           \
            sub-sub-sub-data
```

tldr: How to load unknown amount of data from multiple different subfolders into single pandas dataframe

Comment: Please read [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask, you should provide some code on your attempt to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I can't sure it works because I don't know how is your data looks like. But if all CSV files share the same structure, you can try this:

1. Scan recursively the directory and find all `.csv` files
2. Read each of these into a pandas dataframe, and save it into a list
3. After you finish with all `.csv` files, concat the collected dataframe into a big one

In code:

```
all_df = []

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(MY_DIRECTORY):
    for file in files:
        if not file.endswith('.csv'):
            continue # ignore
        # customize your way to read csv here: headers, index, etc.
        df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(root, file))
        all_df.append(df)

# assume simple concat works
big_dataframe = pd.concat(all_df)
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps!

```
import os 
import pandas as pd
complete_df=pd.DataFrame()
for root, directories, files in os.walk(r'/Users/python/notebooks/'):
    for directory in directories:
        all_csv_files = glob.glob(directory + "/*.csv")
        list_df = []
        if  all_csv_files:
            for filename in all_csv_files:
                df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0)
                list_df.append(df)
    
            complete_df = pd.concat(list_df, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```